# ios Charts 3.0 - Align x labels (dates) with plots

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am having a hard time to migrate library Charts (from Daniel Gindi) from version 2 (Swift 2.3) to 3 (Swift 3).

Basically, I can't have the x labels (dates) aligned correctly with the corresponding plots.

**This is what I had before in version 2:**

In version 2, I had values for days 7, 8, 10 and 11.
So I was missing a day in the middle, but the labels were correctly alined with the plots.
[image: Charts 2]

---

**And here is what I have in version 3:**

In version 3, the "labels" in the x axis have now been replaced by double (for dates, it's a timeInterval since 1970), and formatted via a formatter.
So, indeniably, the graph is more "correct" now, since the chart correctly extrapolates the value for the 9th, but I can't find how to put the labels under the corresponding plots.
[image: Charts 3]

This is my code for the x axis:

```
 let chartView = LineChartView()
 ...
 let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
 xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
 xAxis.labelCount = entries.count
 xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
 xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
 xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true

 // Set the x values date formatter
 let xValuesNumberFormatter = ChartXAxisFormatter()
 xValuesNumberFormatter.dateFormatter = dayNumberAndShortNameFormatter // e.g. "wed 26"
 xAxis.valueFormatter = xValuesNumberFormatter
```

Here is the ChartXAxisFormatter class I created:

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class ChartXAxisFormatter: NSObject {
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter?
}

extension ChartXAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if let dateFormatter = dateFormatter {

            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }

        return ""
    }

}
```

So, the values here are correct, the formatting is correct, the shape of the chart is correct, but the alignment of the labels with the corresponding plots is not good.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I was able to reproduce using Charts 3.0.0 and Charts 3.0.1. At the same time, I have code using Charts 3.0.0 in a separate project which does not suffer from these issues. Perhaps some combination of chart settings surface this bug?

Comment: I had a response of the Charts Github repo: apparently, this happens when using **time intervals** on the x axis, because Charts uses an interpolation to determine which labels to display.

Comment: The cause of the misalignment was 

    xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, got it!

You've got to define a reference time Interval (the "0" for the x axis). And then calculate the additional time interval for each x value.

The ChartXAxisFormatter becomes:

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class ChartXAxisFormatter: NSObject {
    fileprivate var dateFormatter: DateFormatter?
    fileprivate var referenceTimeInterval: TimeInterval?

    convenience init(referenceTimeInterval: TimeInterval, dateFormatter: DateFormatter) {
        self.init()
        self.referenceTimeInterval = referenceTimeInterval
        self.dateFormatter = dateFormatter
    }
}


extension ChartXAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        guard let dateFormatter = dateFormatter,
        let referenceTimeInterval = referenceTimeInterval
        else {
            return ""
        }

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value * 3600 * 24 + referenceTimeInterval)
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

}
```

And, then, when I create my data entries, it works like so:

```
// (objects is defined as an array of struct with date and value)

// Define the reference time interval
var referenceTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 0
if let minTimeInterval = (objects.map { $0.date.timeIntervalSince1970 }).min() {
        referenceTimeInterval = minTimeInterval
    }


    // Define chart xValues formatter
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    formatter.locale = Locale.current

    let xValuesNumberFormatter = ChartXAxisFormatter(referenceTimeInterval: referenceTimeInterval, dateFormatter: formatter)



    // Define chart entries
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for object in objects {
        let timeInterval = object.date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let xValue = (timeInterval - referenceTimeInterval) / (3600 * 24)

        let yValue = object.value
        let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: xValue, y: yValue)
        entries.append(entry)
    }

// Pass these entries and the formatter to the Chart ...
```

The result is much nicer (I removed cubic by the way):
[image]

Comment: I think it's what I did

Comment: What's xValuesFormatter?

Comment: Still I am not able to solve this issue. Can you please explain this clearly? Thanks

Comment: There are a few things missing from @FrédéricAdda answer that I wanted to clarify:  (1) I think you meant to pass in `formatter` into `xValuesNumberFormatter` not `xValuesFormatter` (2) the code doesn't show it but the xValuesNumberFormatter needs to be set on your chart....in other words: `yourChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xValuesNumberFormatter`

Comment: @GarySabo could you please suggest smth on my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828172/swift-chart-library-how-to-display-x-axis-dates-in-a-right-places/58178543#58178543)?

Comment: I also did not get how to config this. What the xValuesFormatter is?

Answer (score 5):

If you exactly know how many labels you need in the x-axis,you can write this code to solve it.For example,If I need seven labels to appear on the x-axis,Then this should be enough.The reason is the chart library is not properly calculating the intervals between the two x-axis points and hence the plot-label mismatch.When we force the library to plot against the given number of labels,The issue seems to be gone.

```
 let xAxis = chart.xAxis
 xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = false
 xAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true) //enter the number of labels here
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var tView:UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView:LineChartView!{
    didSet{
        lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0

        let xAxis = lineChartView.xAxis
        //            xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
        //            xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        //            xaAxis.setLabelCount(6, force: true)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var back: UIButton?
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.lineChartView.delegate = self
    self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.white

    let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar"]
    let dollars1 = [1453.0,2352,5431]
    setChart(months, values: dollars1)
}

func setChart(_ dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0 ..< dataPoints.count {
        dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i]))
    }

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: nil)
    lineChartDataSet.axisDependency = .left
    lineChartDataSet.setColor(UIColor.black)
    lineChartDataSet.setCircleColor(UIColor.black) // our circle will be dark red
    lineChartDataSet.lineWidth = 1.0
    lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 3.0 // the radius of the node circle
    lineChartDataSet.fillAlpha = 1
    lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.black
    lineChartDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.white
    lineChartDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

    var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(lineChartDataSet)


    let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    lineChartView.data = lineChartData
    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)
}


func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    print(entry)
}
```

Comment: Why two "Jan"? Is there a bug in this code?

Comment: i have update the answer and remove the bug

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44554613/2087608

I suspected that these offsets come from adjusting X axis value to a specific time of the day in my case

Here is my code

```
for i in 0..<valuesViewModel.entries.count {
  let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: roundDate(date: valuesViewModel.entries[i].date).timeIntervalSince1970, y: valuesViewModel.entries[i].value)
  dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}



func roundDate(date: Date) -> Date {
  var comp: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
  comp.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
  let truncated = Calendar.current.date(from: comp)!
  return truncated
}
```