# ios Charts 3.0 - X - axis labels(with date values) alignment issue

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

I am having trouble to align x-axis labels especially while displaying dates.

Can anyone please share demo project as I have to use multiple date formats in same graph?

**Example image : as below**

[image: See the image]

Comment: You can see a nice implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959257/2443123